# How does one calculate Rx/a in population genetics?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, population-genetics, population-biology

The ratio of sex-linked to autosome mutation frequencies (R) is Rx/a =(2/3)(2+ α)/(1+ α) for X-linked genes and Ry/a = 2 α /(1+ α) for Y-linked genes. How does one calculate Rx/a, in order to find α?